# Change Sets and Sandbox Refresh

Tags: sandbox, change-set

If I were to create and upload an outbound `Change Set` from a Salesforce Sandbox to Production, then (without Deploying the `Change Set` in Production) refresh the Sandbox, would I still be able to Deploy the `Change Set` in Production after the refresh is complete (even if the object no longer exists due to the refresh)?

Comment: Do you mean "If I were to create and upload" in the beginning of the question? That's a subtle difference that matters. I believe the answer is yes but never tried it. I know that I have few hanging changesets that came from environments that don't exist anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should be able to work without a problem, as the changeset you upload is a snapshot of the moment you press upload, then all the metadata you upload is flattened to (I guess) an xml file, and put available on a production environment. You could test that without having to refresh your sandbox, by simply uploading some code, change the code on your sandbox before doing the deploy on your production, and see the result.

Answer (score 5):

I just had this same scenario. We had change sets to deploy to our production instance after our sandbox refresh, and due to business reasons, we were unable to change when we did our refresh vs release.

Although deleting an outbound change set from the source organization will also delete it from the target organization, this does not appear to be the case between sandbox and production when the sandbox is refreshed.

I have no idea why this is the case, and there is no documentation I can find about it.